# Why font change after converting

Tags: fonts, corel-draw

I have a free font. When i click on convert curve the font changes.
[image]

In the original font and after converting the font why its changes. I tried to weld and intersect. I have coreldraw 12 and coreldraw x6. Well i can see the font in coreldraw 12 as its seen in original and in coreldraw x6 i cant see the same font. Same result. Any suggestion how can i convert my font.

[Font downloaded from here FREE](http://www.1001fonts.com/metal-lord-font.html#character-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's going from uppercase to lowercase. That's half your problem. Perheps you're using a toggle that makes lowercase text render as capitals? Try retyping the text as actual capitals. That should fix the difference between the S's and H.

The second bit is that the resulting shapes get deformed a bit. You mention you use welding - that probably has to do with it. Try not (automatically) welding the shapes. It can also have to do with your grid/resolution. Try turning off all grids and snapping, and making this text larger before converting.

Comment: I have check its not the upper or lower case. When drag from the Insert character to same. In the panel it shows the letter and when drag its different. And welding also give the same result. Plz try to download and install and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: Convert your text to curves in CDR 12 and export the result as someting readable in X6.

Comment: As you can see above when converted the style changes both same in CDR12 AND CDR X6. When drag from the Insert character to same. In the panel it shows the letter and when drag its different. Plz download install try and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
Download the Open type font or convert the TTF to Open type font
and Install and then convert the font for me it work 100%. It work both in CDR12 and CDR x6

[image]